# Getting this message on langchain: The FileType.UNK file type is not supported in partition. Has anyone figured this out?

Tags: python

Getting this message on langchain: The FileType.UNK file type is not supported in partition.

I haven't found much info on the web. The folder only contains PDF documents, nothing else.

This is what I'm running:

```
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Milvus
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader


# Recursive loader to get files  
loader = UnstructuredFileLoader(mydocs, recursive=True)
docs = loader.load()
```

This is what I'm getting:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 10
      8 # Recursive loader to get files  
      9 loader = UnstructuredFileLoader(mydocs, recursive=True)
---> 10 docs = loader.load()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py:86, in UnstructuredBaseLoader.load(self)
     84 def load(self) -> List[Document]:
     85     """Load file."""
---> 86     elements = self._get_elements()
     87     self._post_process_elements(elements)
     88     if self.mode == "elements":

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py:172, in UnstructuredFileLoader._get_elements(self)
    169 def _get_elements(self) -> List:
    170     from unstructured.partition.auto import partition
--> 172     return partition(filename=self.file_path, **self.unstructured_kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/unstructured/partition/auto.py:489, in partition(filename, content_type, file, file_filename, url, include_page_breaks, strategy, encoding, paragraph_grouper, headers, skip_infer_table_types, ssl_verify, ocr_languages, languages, detect_language_per_element, pdf_infer_table_structure, pdf_extract_images, pdf_image_output_dir_path, xml_keep_tags, data_source_metadata, metadata_filename, request_timeout, **kwargs)
    487 else:
    488     msg = "Invalid file" if not filename else f"Invalid file {filename}"
--> 489     raise ValueError(f"{msg}. The {filetype} file type is not supported in partition.")
    491 for element in elements:
    492     element.metadata.url = url

ValueError: Invalid file .... The FileType.UNK file type is not supported in partition.```
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the code sample in the [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/unstructured_file), it seems that the `UnstructeredFileLoader` can only handle one file at a time.

Since it looks like you want to load multiple files from a directory, you should probably try the `DirectoryLoader` instead ([docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/file_directory)):

```
import bs4
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader

loader = DirectoryLoader("path/to/dir", glob="**/*.pdf")

docs = loader.load()

print( docs[0].page_content[:100] )    # Prints the first 100 chars from the first retrieved doc
```

**Note**: with the optional `glob` parameter you can further specify which file types to load (in the example `.pdf` files).